# Create table and insert records in table in Android using RubyMotion

Tags: sqlite, insert, rubymotion, oncreate

I am creating database class and creating object of that class on button click but controller is not hitting that class here is my database code

```
class DataStore < Android::Database::SQLite::SQLiteOpenHelper
  DATABASE_NAME = "MyFriendsDatabase"

  def initialize(context)
    puts "consructor in database"
    #super(context, Name, Factory, Version)
    #context - this is used to create database
    #name - name of the database file
    #factory - A cursor factory(usually pass nil)
    #Version - the version of database. this number is used to identify if there is an upgrade or downgrade of the database
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, nil, 1)
  end

  def onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion)
    #db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS credentials")
    onCreate(db)
  end
  #create
  def onCreate(database)
    puts "table creation"
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE credentials(username TEXT, password TEXT)")
  end
  #insert
  def add_credentials(username, password)
    puts "inserting data in table"
    values = ContenValues.new(2)
    values.put("username", username)
    values.put("password", password)
    getWritableDatabase.insert("credentials", "username", values)
  end
  #retrieve
  def get_credentials
    puts "coming here &&&&&&&&&&&"
    cursor = getReadableDatabase.rawQuery("select * from credentials", nil)
    cursor
  end

  #deleting all records

  def deleteAll
    getWritable.delete("credentials", nil, nil)
  end

end
```

the code which will execute on button click is

```
database = DataStore.new(self)
      database.add_credentials(@text_box_value.getText.toString, @text_box.getText.toString)
      puts database.get_credentials
```

anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you edit your answer to fix those code blocks, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of RubyMotion Android. You can't do super or override Java class constructors from Ruby. See this link http://www.rubymotion.com/developers/guides/manuals/android/project-management/#_extending_classes_with_java

Also I am making something for this so you won't have to deal with the raw SQL. You can if you want (or need to). I will support this in my gem anyway. I will edit my answer when I have released it. Thanks. It's not ready yet.